# How to use multiple Icomoon font same iOS Project?

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

My project already has a icommon font file. I missed the .json file to retrieve the font. Unable to add another font icomoon font in that project. It overrides the previous font.

Answer (score 0):

I tried generate icomoon font with different font name it works.

To change the Font name in icomoon please refer the image below.

[image]